# Foreign key to a parent table of a parent table

Tags: sql, database

Let’s imagine three tables: Countries, Areas (part of country), Cities. I obviously need a foreign key from City to Area and a foreign key from Area to Country. Do I need a FK from City to Country? What a pros and contras of having such a FK?

Comment: I'd guess smaller countries don't even have separate areas. How do you plan to store their cities?

Comment: it’s just an example. let’s imagine a country always has areas

Comment: Then you don't _need_ it. However, in practice it _could_ be useful.

Comment: I understand that it is not required. But what are the cases when it might be useful? and what are reasons to not use it

Comment: Having multiple routes between 2 entities is generally bad practice and should be avoided

Comment: @NickW I initially felt that, that’s why I asked this question. But what are the proofs of your statement?

Comment: Because having multiple routes between two objects can cause inconsistency e.g. you can link from City to Area to Country and link from City to Country and for those 2 paths can lead to different countries for the same city

Answer (score 0):

Not that you don't need it, you shouldn't have it at all if you want to keep data model normalized. The answer is "Yes, I do want to have it normalized" and "No, I don't want to have a foreign key between cities and countries".

Because, if there's a foreign key from cities to countries, you can update CITIES table and "move" that particular city into another country, while its are stays in the "old" country and query returns ambiguous result - that city belongs to BOTH countries at the same time.

For example (as I live in Croatia), there's a *borderline* county between Hungary and Croatia (this map calls it "Medimurska HR") and there's a city named "Cakovec":

[image]

Sample tables (with a foreign key between cities and countries):

```
SQL> create table countries
  2    (id_country number primary key,
  3     name       varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create table areas
  2    (id_area    number primary key,
  3     name       varchar2(20),
  4     id_country number references countries
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> create table cities
  2    (id_city    number primary key,
  3     name       varchar2(20),
  4     id_area    references areas,
  5     id_country references countries
  6    );

Table created.
```

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From countries;

ID_COUNTRY NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Croatia
         2 Hungary

SQL> select * From areas;

   ID_AREA NAME                 ID_COUNTRY
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Medimurska HR                 1
         2 Zala HU                       2

SQL> select * from cities;

   ID_CITY NAME                    ID_AREA ID_COUNTRY
---------- -------------------- ---------- ----------
         1 Cakovec                       1          1

SQL>
```

Query - which *ignores* foreign key between cities and countries, says that Cakovec is in Croatia:

```
SQL> select y.name city, a.name area, c.name country
  2  from cities y join areas a on a.id_area = y.id_area
  3                join countries c on c.id_country = a.id_country;

CITY                 AREA                 COUNTRY
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Cakovec              Medimurska HR        Croatia
```

Query - which takes a "shortcut" and joins cities and countries - says the same: Cakovec is in Croatia:

```
SQL> select y.name city, a.name area, c.name country
  2  from cities y join areas a on a.id_area = y.id_area
  3                join countries c on c.id_country = y.id_country;

CITY                 AREA                 COUNTRY
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Cakovec              Medimurska HR        Croatia

SQL>
```

If we update `CITIES` and "move" Cakovec to Hungary:

```
SQL> update cities set id_country = 2 where id_city = 1;

1 row updated.
```

and run the same `select` statements again, the first one (that joins cities to areas to countries) says that Cakovec is still in Croatia because its **area** remained in Croatia:

```
SQL> select y.name city, a.name area, c.name country
  2  from cities y join areas a on a.id_area = y.id_area
  3                join countries c on c.id_country = a.id_country;

CITY                 AREA                 COUNTRY
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Cakovec              Medimurska HR        Croatia
```

However, the 2nd query - the "shortcut" one - says that Cakovec is in Hungary:

```
SQL> select y.name city, a.name area, c.name country
  2  from cities y join areas a on a.id_area = y.id_area
  3                join countries c on c.id_country = y.id_country;

CITY                 AREA                 COUNTRY
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Cakovec              Medimurska HR        Hungary
```

So, which one of these is true?

---

Therefore, once again: remove foreign key from cities to countries.